# If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ converges absolutely, then the sum of the Cauchy product is equal to the product of two sums.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have read a proof and I want to figure out my understanding is correct or not.

Let  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=A$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n=B$.

Since I want to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n=AB$, I need to estimate $|AB-\sum_{k=0}^N c_k|$.

To get our goal, we need some estimates:

1. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |b_n|$
   converge, Let $$M=\max\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|,\sum_{n=0}^\infty
   |b_n|\}+1$$
2. Define $r_n:=\sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_k|$ and $s_n:=\sum_{k=n}^\infty
   |b_k|$. Note that $\{r_n\}$ and $\{s_n\}$ are decreasing  sequence
   and $\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=0$, so $$\exists
   N_0\in\Bbb N \ni \forall N\gt N_0, r_N<\varepsilon \text{ and }
   s_N<\varepsilon$$

Now, we start to estimate $|AB-\sum_{k=0}^N c_k|$.

For $N\gt N_0$, we have $$|AB-\sum_{k=0}^N c_k| \\= |AB-\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N a_k\Biggr) \Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N b_k\Biggr) +\sum_{N<i+j\le2N, i\le N \text{ and }j\le N}a_ib_j| \\=|\bigl(A-\sum_{k=0}^N a_k\bigr)\bigl(B-\sum_{k=0}^N b_k\bigr)+\bigl(A-\sum_{k=0}^N a_k\bigr)\sum_{k=0}^N b_k+\bigl(B-\sum_{k=0}^N b_k\bigr)\sum_{k=0}^N a_k+\sum_{N<i+j\le2N, i\le N \text{ and }j\le N}a_ib_j| \\\le|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k| \biggr)|+|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N |b_k|\biggr)|+|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N |a_k|\biggr)|+|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \color{blue}{\mathscr d_k}| \\=A+B+C+D$$, where $$A:=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k| \biggr)|$$$$B:=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N |b_k|\biggr)|$$$$C:=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N |a_k|\biggr)|$$ $$D:=|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \color{blue}{\mathscr d_k}|$$, where $\color{blue}{\mathscr d_k}=\sum_{i+j=k}|a_i||b_j|$.

To discuss each term separately:

1. $A=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty
   |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k| \biggr)|$ is a product
   of two numbers and if we add more terms of $a_n$, we have
   $$A=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty
   |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k|
   \biggr)|\le|\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^\infty
   |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |b_k| \biggr)|\le
   M\varepsilon$$
2. $B=|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^N
   |b_k|\biggr)|$ is a product of two numbers and if we add more terms
   of $b_n$, we have their upper bound,
   $$B\le|\biggl(\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty
   |a_k|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^\infty |b_k|\biggr)|\le M\varepsilon$$

   Similary for $C\le M\varepsilon$
3. $D=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \color{blue}{\mathscr d_k}$ is the Cauchy
   product of $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty
   |b_n|$, and if I add more terms of $a_n$ the sum of Cauchy product
   will become bigger, then we have $$D\le\biggl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty
   |a_n|\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |b_n|\biggr)\le
   M\varepsilon$$

Hence, we obtain $$\forall N\gt N_0, |AB-\sum_{k=0}^N c_k|\le 4M\varepsilon $$

Q.E.D.

The original proof I read in the last step to obtain the difference of $|AB-\sum_{k=0}^N c_k|$ is smaller than $4M\varepsilon$ has no explanation so I want to figure out the details. I spend most of the time thinking about the  meaning of notion $\biggl(\sum|a_n|\biggr)\biggl(\sum|b_n|\biggr)$ and I think sometimes it means the real finite numbers and sometimes it means the Chauchy product of two series. Although I know that if both of them converge then the sum of the Cauchy product equal to the product of the sums.

Hope someone can find some mistakes, thanks a lot.

Comment: The Cauchy product series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n$ with $c_n =  \sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j$. This is not the same as your $c_n$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I think my Cauchy product $\sum c_n$ is what you mention.

Comment: You define $c_k = \sum_{i+j=k} |a_i||b_j|$. With "my" $c_k$ you have $\lvert c_k \rvert \le d_k = \sum_{i+j=k} |a_i||b_j|$. You show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_k$ converges. The comparison test proves then that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$ converges absolutely.

Comment: @PaulFrost the Cauchy product $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \color{blue}{\mathscr c_k}$ there is the Cauchy product of $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|$ and $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |b_n|$. I try to mark some color to identify that it is not the same as the original one.

Comment: I suggest that you use another symbol, not another color.

Comment: thanks, I have edited.